# removing double quotes from column header in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, double-quotes, columnheader

I am trying to understand the intuition behind the following line of code.

I know that it is removing double quotes from the column header within a dataframe, although can anyone please help me understand how it is doing that?

```
df.columns = [col[1:-1] for col in df.columns]
```

Thanks

Comment: df.colunms returns a `pd.Series` of the column names, then using *list comprehension*, you can iterate through the individual column names and use, *index slicing* to select from the second character in a column through the second to last character in that column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`df.columns = ...` is the part of line that assigns the list on the right hand side to the columns.

Then the right hand side is a list comprehension, meaning it can be understood like a for loop.

Then, in python, a string is an array of characters. `for col in columns` mean you iterate over each string in the list of columns. Each `col` is an array. If that string has quotes, then it looks like `"xxxx"`. So the first and the last elements of the array are quotes.

`col[1:-1]` is the way to slice the array from the second element to the one before last.

So when you put all these things next to each other, in your case you end up removing quotes.

Answer (score 2):

This is to take 2nd index to 2nd last index in a `column names` string for each column

Example:- 
[image]

If `column name` string is of size less than 3, then it gives you empty string as `column name`

Example -

[image]